# Force VPN adapter to use wireless NIC?

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

Shrewsoft VPN client under Win7 Ultimate x64

In one of my offices, I have two networks available. One is a wired network authenticated via MAC. The other is a a wireless network.

Occasionally, I have to VPN to a client's office to fix some issues from this location. The wireless network allows me to do this; the wired network, for some reason, blocks VPN traffic.

At the moment, I have to disconnect the ethernet cable for the wired network to force my VPN client to use that network. When I'm done, I reconnect the wired cable to get access to those resources.

Is it possible to force the VPN client to use the wireless NIC so that I don't have to go through this? I'm not trying to bridge the connections; I would just prefer to not have to disconnect a cable everytime I fire up the VPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can create a persistent static route to force the vpn packets through a particular adapter. ( https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2050253 )

I think I got this to work:

1. Open an administrative command prompt.
2. Run `route print` This will show all the interfaces at the top and your existing routes
3. Find the interface number for the network you want to connect through
4. Run `ipconfig` and find the gateway for the network you want to connect through
5. Finally look at the ipaddress your vpn connects through and use

   route ADD [ipaddress of vpn connection] MASK [subnet mask] [gateway IP address of network connection]  IF [interface number of network connection]

as thus:

```
route add 1.2.3.4 MASK 255.255.255.255 5.6.7.8 IF 21
```

where 1.2.3.4 is the ip address of the VPN, 5.6.7.8 is the gateway of the network connection that you got from ipconfig above, and 21 is the interface number of the network connection you want to use.

more info on adding routing tables where I found it [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-add-route-to-tcpip-routing-table-with-windows-routing-and-remote-access-console-or-dos-prompt/)